# Registering a KeyPress Event Method in C# "DialPad.Designer.CS" page

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Im designing a dialerPad form using Windows form, there is a textbox which should only take numbers and not text, my problem is that when i add the code

```
private void txtDialedNumber_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    //Blaah Blaah Code;
}
```

but its not getting registered in the other DialPad.Designer.CS page. For example the fallowing code registers TextChangedEvent

```
this.txtDailedNumber.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.txtDailedNumber_TextChanged);
```

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Could you share some more code and tell us exactly where it is failing? You should also retag your question. Nothing about vb or wpf in the question as far as I can see.

Comment: Please mention clearly - Is it a keypress event on a form, textbox or a button ?

Comment: @Niraj: It's clearly a TextBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to simplify Greg's answer.

Select the text box > go to properties > events tab> KeyPress Event > select the method `this.txtDailedNumber.KeyPress`

You are done.

Comment: This is what i wanted.. Thanks Niraj.. From next time i would make my questions clear... :)

Answer (score 5):

You should never change *.designer.cs files manually.

What you should be doing is opening the design view of your form, selecting the object, and then setting the event handler in the objects properties:

[image]

Alternatively, if you want to register event handler manually (instead of using the designer), just put it under the InitializeComponent() call in the constructor for your form.

Comment: He hasn't changed any designer code. He just mentions the eventhandler function stated in the designer.

Comment: @Niraj: I didn't say he did... The answer still applies doesn't it?

Comment: Yes it applies, I take back my comment. My mistake :)

Comment: The screenshot gives the better answer :)